# First experiments with buffer overflow

Tags: c++, c, linux, stack-overflow, buffer-overflow

I've started reading about buffer overflow and how hackers use it to execute custom code instead of the regular compiled one and now I'm trying to reproduce some basic situations, with a vurnerable function that copy data into a char array with the unsafe strcpy.

The point is that **when I change the return address with one of an assembly instrution of a function defined in the program it works fine, while when I inject code directly in bytes it returned SEGMENTATION FAULT.**

---

I'm using the Kali distribution x64 v3.18


I've disabled the address space layout randomization (ASLR):

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
```

And disabled the stack protection code added by the compiler:

```
gcc -g -fno-stack-protector exbof.c -o exbof
```

**Code:**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    char buffer[500] = {0};
    strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
./exbof `perl -e 'print "x90"x216;          // nop sled 
                  print CUSTOM_CODE;        // my code  
                  print "xff"x(500 - 216 - CODE_LENGTH);     // fill empty space
                  print "xff"xOFFSET        // distance between the last byte 
                                            // of buffer and the return address 
                  printf("\\x%lx", BUFFER_ADDRESS + int(rand(26)) * 8);'`
```

**Output:**

```
Segmentation Fault
```

**In GDB:**

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007fffffffxyzt in ?? ()
```

I've used GDB to debug it and **the code write the new address corrrectly in the stack.**

I'm using a shellcode exec found online, but I've also tried to inject a piece of code in bytes from my program and **when I checked with GDB the assembly code injected turned out to be valid code and exactly the same of the original one.**

**It seems to me that any address out of the .text memory segment doesn't work.**

Suggestions?

Comment: Its not totally clear to me what you're getting at, but writing executable code into a buffer isn't going to execute it. There may be some confusion that the program executable and the stack are not typically stored in the same place in memory.

Comment: Because people do stuff like this for evil, it has become much harder over the years. Not hard enough, mind you.

Comment: @vu1p3n0x It all about stack overflow, buffer is 500 byte long and I wrote out of the buffer var so that I override the return address of the main function and when the program reach the `retq` instruction the address in the RIP (EIP x64) register contains the address I provided, so it will jump to that address. That's the idea.

Comment: I would guess the stack is marked as nonexecutable. Perhaps try http://linux.die.net/man/8/execstack ?

Comment: Does injecting the address of main work as expected?

Comment: @andars You're right. Thanks!

Comment: @andars Yeah,  it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:**

As suggested by @andars, it's necessary to set up the flag that mark the stack as executable.

So, if you want to try this and start playing with buffer overflows, you have to:

- disable the address space layout randomization (ASLR):

  `echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space`
- disable the stack protection code added by the compiler:

  `gcc -g -fno-stack-protector your_program.c -o your_program`
- set up a flag in the program header to mark the stack as executable:

  `execstack -s your_program`

  - or you can do it directly at assembly time or at link time:

    `gcc -g -fno-stack-protector -z execstack your_program.c -o your_program`